# Version control systems for hardware projects?

Tags: project-management

What are some of the good versioning systems for hardware projects? Is there equivalents of Google Code, CVS and SVN? Are such version control systems suitable for hardware projects involving PCB files, schematics..(even firmware code)?

Comment: Great question! Would love to see some repository examples included in answers.

Comment: +1 For recognizing that the HW projects could benefit from source control.  The guys I work with seem to have a tough time realizing this.

Comment: I've been using Mercurial to version circuit boards for a while now, and it's saved my butt a couple times. Definitely a good idea.

Comment: I use the gEDA suite of tools for EDA and track things in git. I recently wrote some git hooks that automatically generates .png images of any schematics or PCBs that have been modified and adds them to the commit. This allows me to take advantage of GitHub's image diff. PCB and gschem also have native diff tools that work with git that do something similar locally. My hooks are here: https://github.com/BenBergman/.git_hooks Example project that uses them: https://github.com/BenBergman/uJoypad

Comment: Answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458224/7277402](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458224/7277402)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Basically, all VCS systems can handle text & binary files gracefully.
Of course you cannot merge binary ones.

So as long as you are not using obsolete things like CVS you will be good with ANY system.

Comment: I use CVS for all my projects (software and hardware, with PCB, firmware, tools, etc.) and have no problem. Sure, CVS is obsolete, but I have 20 years of project history and no converter worked to migrate my repositories to Mercurial, or SVN.

Comment: Then a pragmatic way is simply too leave the old stuff in CVS, and then put new stuff in the new system...

Comment: CVS a beautiful system when compared with the horror that is Microsoft Visual Source Safe, which I'm locked into for a project I'm working on at the moment. Blech.

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer You know you are on the negative side on the scale when you are comparing two "not that nice" things with each other ;)

Comment: @KevinVermeer, I had to use sourcesafe, the bane of the version control world. My last boss allowed complete neglect of version control because of it.

Comment: @Axeman don't know if you've tried cvs2git? That was quite a relief after I tried `git-cvsimport`.

Comment: Answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458224/7277402](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458224/7277402)

Answer (score 17):

I've used Subversion with Altium before. It worked successfully, but at the time the lack of a diff tool made it less useful than version control is with code. I still think it was worth doing, even without diff capability.

For firmware, Subversion or Git are both great. If you haven't used Git before, try Subversion first (even though it will make learning Git later harder).

Altium has recently introduced a diff tool for schematics and PCBs, so I expect that Subversion would now be great, modulo the usual insanity that EDA vendors manage to build into their products.

I've been meaning to try this out with the new diff tool; if I do, I'll try to remember to post a link to the repo here as an example.

**Update**

I tried this out, and I have to say that I'm a little underwhelmed with the Altium diff tool. It's functional, but the changes between board revs are substantial enough that it's not that useful, at least for me. Having seen this, I've decided to forget about the diff tool and just use Github. Here's the repo if you're interested: https://github.com/rascalmicro/pcb

Comment: Did you use the integrated SVN GUI (with Altium) or something external?

Comment: Newest Altium with SVN is great, although i'll add that PCB/schematic revisions aren't nearly as critical as they are in code.  If you're dealing with more than 3-4 max schematic / PCB release revisions something probably when very wrong in the design or requirements phases.

Comment: @Mark: Are you talking about the Release 10 beta, or Summer 09?

Comment: I'm on summer 09 atm, i don't know exactly at what point the schematic/PCB diff tool was added, there was a several year period where i wasn't using altium so my use of 'newest' was probably inaccurate in terms of when this feature was added.

Comment: If the changes between board revs are substantial enough that it's not useful, you're not committing often enough.  Commit early, commit often!  Use tags to track board revs.

Comment: @reemrevnivek: When I wrote "board revs," I mean releases sent out for fabrication. I can commit more often, but that won't change the differences between releases, though it would allow me to see them in small steps, which could be useful. What system are you using? Is it worthwhile?

Comment: I'm using SVN, and it is definitely worthwhile. My system is this: I hit the save button, I should proabably make a commit. I follow the changes by reading the commit messages like "Added part X to library" or "Added test pads to I2C and SPI busses." Releases sent out for fabrication are entirely different, use `svn cp trunk/ tags/releaseX/` to take a snapshot of the release.  You can then diff releaseX/file and releaseY/file if you want to see changes between releases, or you can browse the commit logs and see individual changes.  Branches help modularize the flood of commits.

Comment: Answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458224/7277402](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458224/7277402)

Answer (score 10):

I use VisualSVN Server + TortoiseSVN client, and it works just fine

Answer (score 7):

I use Google Code to host [Super OSD](http://super-osd.googlecode.com/), an electronics project of mine.

I exclusively use the gEDA suite to manage my schematics and PCBs. Usefully, gEDA produces text files (which are mostly human readable, although it's difficult to interpret them) for the schematics, instead of binary blobs, like Eagle. For example, [this is a diff between two schematics](http://code.google.com/p/super-osd/source/diff?spec=svne5f0a5cc4a9a51de29d66d37698e259c9954b0ef&r=e5f0a5cc4a9a51de29d66d37698e259c9954b0ef&format=side&path=/hardware/V3.2+Lite/mcu.sch&old_path=/hardware/V3.2+Lite/mcu.sch&old=ca1233a25cb1607317c77294660256c932b88a1f), one about 5 days old and one I just pushed. It's not particularly useful as you can't actually see much changes in text files, but it can show relative change - i.e. massive rework, vs. single component change - and it does let you go back to prior versions.

Comment: +1 for the use of text-based formats for files.  Disk space is cheap, and compression of text is easy.  I wish that binary blobs were less common.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to use something that works well with binaries.  If you are using binaries a lot and sharing with others, it might be beneficial to implement a locking mechanism on those binary files.  We've run into lots of issues with using Subversion with binary files and sharing with others that arose due to a lack of locking semantics and over-writing/merging binary files together.  Adding a locking mechanism on those files removes human error in communication on who edited/changed the binary file.

If you haven't used version control before, I recommend reading up on the different ways they work, and select one to meet your needs that you and/or your team can be comfortable with.  Distributed version control systems provide many benefits over client-server systems, but tend to be more complicated to work with.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use Google Code or a SVN repo? As this is a revision control system. There is no defined use for it. It is just incredibly useful for multiple developers and monitoring changes in source code.

Comment: Have you done this? Putting binaries into SVN or Mercurial has turned out terribly for me.

Comment: No i haven't but i have used SVN for not just source code. Things Like PDFs and .txt files.

Comment: @Tyblu what do you mean by terrible? I've done it with schematic and layout files and its worked great for me with subversion.

Comment: I can't follow changes to EAGLE files with Mercurial. It looks like the entire file is different. Do you have a repository I can peek at?

Comment: @tyblu that's why you add comments when you check in files :)

Comment: @tyblu - I've been managing huge (5 GB +) folders of Binary PCB Projects in SVN for years now, with no issues. What was your problem?

Answer (score 3):

> I've used Subversion with Altium before.

I do use SVN with Altium integration for schematic capture: it works well. I must say that the diff viewer is better than having nothing, because my SchDoc files are binary, ie impossible to compare otherwise!
I use the SVN client integrated in Altium Designer in parallel with TortoiseSVN with no problem. Altium's client is a bit limited in terms of SVN features. I do my "tags" with Tortoise.

My opinion is based on Altium Designer 10 build 27009, and version 13.1 build 27559.

Answer (score 2):

svn, hg, and git all work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid git. It doesn't handle large repositories well. And your repositories will get large unless you

1. Have binary schematic files that only change somewhat when they change
2. Turn on treat binaries as text.

Comment: Well... You should have many small repos, one repo per project.

Comment: @Johan - ......Yeah.... Good luck with that maintenance nightmare. Anyways, I have 1 repo per client (about 4, repositories, now), with many sub-projects, and it works pretty well. SVN, at least, seems to be able to handle 5+ GB of binary data without too much trouble.

Comment: @ConnorWolf I'd be interested to hear how you're doing that. We do one Git repository per project, and have had no problems. Not having a single repository per project sounds like a maintenance nightmare to me.

Comment: @MattYoung - It's not a big deal. `svnaccess.conf` for ACL needs, and it works without major issue. And I don't have to be constantly creating new repos, which is kind of a PITA (apache `mod-svn` is cranky). The biggest repo DB on the server is 5.1 Gigabytes, ~930 revisions (and that's all me, too(.

Comment: SVN, at least (probably git too) seems to store binary diffs, rather then complete copies of a file, so it's impressively space-efficient.

Comment: @ConnorWolf git doesn't. Git stores a compressed snapshot of every changed file. But, really: altium projects and the like compress really well, so this rarely becomes a serious problem.

Comment: @ConnorWolf re: maintenance nightmare: 8 years later: git-submodules are probably what you want here. Makes sense especially if you share e.g. standard tooling things between multiple projects or customers.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Wow, yeah, that comment didn't age well, and I've been fully git-based for 5+ years now..

Comment: @ConnorWolf it's incredibly nice that you answer to comments that came 5 years late :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not a real version control system but Dropbox handles also revision of files an makes them available for different people on different OSes. - poor mans version control system ;)

Comment: as someone who've worked with teams before: **Please** don't do this. Dropbox is not a *poor man's version control system*. It's file share/archival system. You don't have to use git to its fullest extent for it to be more useful, really! Dropbox does all the things wrong that even CVS did right (how to deal with newer revisions, how to exchange changes, how to mark specific revisions), it's really **not a version control system**.

Answer (score 1):

I was at the Maker Faire in San Mateo this past weekend and met some reps from a new (to me) company called [Up-Verter](http://upverter.com/). They are basically building an electrical CAD tool that runs in "the cloud" (i.e. in your browser) and is conceptually built around collaboration, so should deal with merge/diff and the usual versioning stuff.

I haven't tried it yet, and it looks a little bit green still (don't think you can actually do pcb layout yet, just schematics), but it's kind of intriguing. They claimed they could import Eagle files, which is a plus.

I also talked to the Eagle reps at the Element 14 tent, and they indicated that they are moving to an XML format, which is kind of a big step toward making versioning of schematics and layout more plausible... all interesting advancements on this front!

Answer (score 1):

> **Altium good news!**

Altium added support to **Git control version** like you can see in the [Release Notes for Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/Release+Notes+for+Altium+Designer#!ReleaseNotesforAltiumDesigner-Version18%C2%B70%C2%B712).

To know how to use you can follow this [Using Version Control](https://www.altium.com/documentation/1.0/display/NEXUS/((Using+Version+Control))_AD#!UsingVersionControl-AddaprojecttoGit) guide.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a very good question. Since FPGAs fall into the category of "hardware", you might be interested in a version-control friendly project structure I propose for FPGA projects:

http://www.saardrimer.com/fpgaproj/

I think the ideas and concepts could easily be applies to other hardware projects, and in general. (Comments on this proposal are very welcome, btw.)

Comment: The link isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using multiple Mercurial (HG) repos (one per project) for this but as most Version Control Systems will experience, the repos are getting larger and larger.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Boar](http://code.google.com/p/boar/). It is designed ground-up to handle huge files and repositories. 100 GB or more of binary data is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add a link to HgInit, an excellent introduction to Mercurial if you decide to go that route. Personally I use Git, but they're very similar in terms of architecture (both are distributed version control systems). The distributed nature of them makes them great for working in well, "distributed" teams. :)

http://hginit.com/

Comment: While Mercurial is a good source control system for 'pure' software projects, many of its advantages are lost on projects that deal with essentially purely binary files as it is unable to sensibly merge things. The lessons of HgInit will not make any sense unless you are only doing software.

Answer (score 0):

OpenPLM seems to offer some aspects of what you are looking for although it does not seem to be in active development (http://www.openplm.org/trac/discussion/topic/93).

Maybe take a look at https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/erpnext-git-github-for-open-source-hardware-call-for-beta-user-s/18006 ("ERPNext: Git / Github for Open Source Hardware – Call For Beta User(s)")

Answer (score 0):

This is worth thinking about for any ascii descriptions of hardware. Once a human readable description for the hardware is adopted any modern revision control system (RCS) works pretty well. Circuit layouts are typically fully described by Gerber files, UML describes other parts, which are fully ascii descriptions. Less standard ascii formats exist for schematics, mechanical layout and so on (KiCAD for instance).

Adoption is more a practical issue, it requires a recognized requirement for good revision control, including a meaningful diff. Which also often means giving up Word, Excel, PowerPoint, etc. A very difficult argument against managers and MBAs, but arguably regulated industries like Medical Devices, Aviation and Military already require good revision control.

As others have pointed out, most modern RCS will revision control binary files, which is very useful for archiving and identifying versions - but any electronic document management system (EDMS), Agile for instance, can assign a revision number to an arbitrary binary. Boring.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not free, and is hardly bug free, Altium vault does a sterling job; I can roll back to any commit point easily (just as any VCS should do) very easily.

In this area, Altium is *way* ahead of the premium (Mentor and Cadence) tools.

I do *not* work for Altium but this tool, despite the current issues, make complete hardware versioning very simple.

Comment: And that is probably the one thing the Vault is good for...

Comment: The UNIX way; do one thing and do it very well.

Answer (score 0):

For Firmware part I use git to manage versioning, and use git information in naming output hex file and as hard-coded variables also inside the code to show for users in startup messages though the debugging console. I wrote a blog post about it "[How to Use GIT to Manage Firmware Versions](https://atadiat.com/en/e-how-to-use-git-to-manage-firmware-versions/)"